# How big of an opening needed for WiFi signal with ESP32 in a metal box?

Tags: esp32

I am using an [ESP32](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/espressif-systems/ESP32-S3-WROOM-1-N8R8/15295891) which has the antenna on the PCB for a project.  It will be enclosed in a metal box/frame. how big of a hole should I put in the metal box/frame so the WiFi signal can go in and out without issues?

Comment: 'without issues' - there's going to have to be some compromise. Metal is going to shield the antenna. You might be better off getting an ESP32 module with an external antenna connection.

Comment: The opening will be directly above the ESP32.

Comment: It will only radiate/receive from the top. Depends on what your requirements are. Nevertheless, it should be easy to test before you commit to a solution.

Comment: How far the antenna is away from the hole is just as important.

Comment: An opening > wavelength/2 so at 2.4 GHz that is about 6 cm, will appear as "open" in general, but with the close proximity, MIMO and what not going on, that won't hold true here. I would however start with something in that low cm range and see if you can live with the attenuation.

Comment: is an external antenna not an option?

Comment: The antenna will be 1.5-2cm away from the hole.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This supposed to be a comment but got too long so I put as an answer. Doesn't have to be upvoted or accepted.

It's not that simple because

- The relative position and orientation of the antenna (or the module) are important.
- The resonance frequency of the metal box is important.

So you'll need not only an opening on top, but also on bottom or even on the sides as well. Although the metal is a good reflector (generally), radiation of the module antenna will be partly absorbed and partly reflected by the metal depending on the material's properties. Each reflection might bring some phase and therefore cause the other signals to be disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be an external monopole mounted on the box. Second best would be a slot antenna cut in the box, fed with a short coax cable from the PCB. If you're forced to use a PCB-based antenna inside a box, cut an opening that has a circumference of 1 wavelength at 2.4 GHz. This approximates a slot antenna and will be at least partially excited by the RF coming from the PCB. Expect a 10 to 20 dB loss in efficiency, or a 3 - 10 x reduction in range, but it could be worse.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So based on my math the circumference of the hole [speed of wave] = [frequency][wavelength] --> [speed of wave]/[frequency] = [wavelength].

So 0.125 meters circumference hole, correct?

Comment: Assuming 3.0e8 = speed of wave and 2.4e9 = frequency.

Comment: It can be a bit smaller (~85% of the free-space wavelength) but you're not creating a precise design and will have to experiment. Some theory behind the "cavity backed slot antenna" here: https://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/aperture/slot2.php